# Very Basic JS Coding, and SoundManager2 or not?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-streaming

I would like to include an audio/possible video player on my website with the following attributes:

- Must be placeable via a `<div>`;
- Styled via CSS;
- Can read all ID3 info;
- Can pull the file from a database (probably GoDaddy's Easy Database);
- No flash;
- Transferrable to smartphones etc.

I have been herded to SoundManager2 which appears to fit the bill, but I seem to be having real trouble just making a clickable image to begin playing my mp3.  I have zero JS skills so am going from silly basic and building up slowly.  I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is there another media player that is better suited?
2. I can't create a Fiddle with what I have so far, but this is the very simple HTML - what is going wrong?:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>

   <script src="script/soundmanager2.js"></script>

   <script>

   // Path to Flash Files
   soundManager.url = 'swf/';
   soundManager.onload(function(){
     // SM2 is ready to Play Audio

   // Create "mySound"
   soundManager.createSound({
   id:"mySound",
   url:"audiofiles/my.mp3",
   onfinish:function(){window.location.href='index.html}});
   };

   // Play File
   //soundManager.play('mySound','my.mp3');});
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="Previous" border="0" width="400" height="400" onclick="soundManager.play('mySound',{volume:100})";>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

I had copied this code from [another website](http://en.wikiaudio.org/SoundManager2%3aHow_to_play_and_trigger_sound), but I have a sneaking suspicion that the code was incomplete, so any help would be...err...helpful.

Comment: SO doesn't charge by the character; please don't use URL shorteners.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise it was a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I operate the website you say you took the code from. I updated it and it should work. Make sure you do **both sections in the tutorial**. The second section assumes that you are using the same file structure as the first. This should work completley fine now:

http://en.wikiaudio.org/SoundManager2:How_to_play_and_trigger_sound

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The second section now works.  I had done this from start to finish previously but couldn't get the onClick to work.  Though just to let you know, the example has an opening HTML tag but no closing tag, and has a closing p tag but no opening tag...UPDATE: I also realise that I didn't make clear that after trying your original code I went back to SoundManager2, took code from there and adapted it with your code. That was quite important really, so should have mentioned it.

Comment: The wiki software I use was acting weird and buggy so I left the tag off